# Android Application running memory size limit

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview, out-of-memory

Is it possible to limit the size of an android application? (say in Manifest)

The case is: The client want the app not to be exceed, say 20 MB. But available memory in device is, say 50 MB. The application is having Webview in one of Activities which keeps on increasing size and hence increases the overall app size. 
So is it possible: When webview is not needed (set to null already) and overall memory size >30 MB. GC is called forcefully?
Note: It is assured that other components and activities don't need more than,say 5 MB memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to limit the size of an android application? (say in Manifest)

Not really. The heap limit of an app is determined by the device, not the app. The only thing an app can do is have `android:largeHeap` to request a *larger* heap; there is no way to ask for a smaller-than-normal heap.

Also note that allocations that you make via the NDK do not count towards the heap limit. For that, you are completely on your own.

> The client want the app not to be exceed, say 20 MB

Your client is welcome to build their own device or ROM mod that can enforce this limit, at least for allocations within the Dalvik/ART virtual machines.

Or, your client should not be using Android, but rather something else, like embedded Linux, where they have much more control over how memory gets used.

> But available memory in device is, say 50 MB.

The amount of available system RAM on the device does not directly tie to the app's heap limit.

> When webview is not needed (set to null already) and overall memory size >30 MB. GC is called forcefully?

You are welcome to attempt to implement this yourself. It will not work in general, but you are welcome to implement it.

Once the virtual machine allocates memory from the OS, it will only return that memory to the OS when that memory is no longer being used. Dalvik -- the virtual machine used on Android 4.4 and below -- does not compact the heap, and therefore even though you may cause some memory to be garbage-collected, that may not reduce your overall heap size.

Also note that some of the system RAM consumed by a `WebView` involves the underlying WebKit/Blink libraries. As I understand it, those are dynamically loaded when you first use a `WebView` (which is why your first `WebView` may take a moment to load up). But those code segments probably are not released until the process is terminated.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response!